# Possible syntax errors with first c++

Tags: c++

Hey everyone I'm working on a project for school, I'm pretty sure the code itself is right, but I don't know why my IDE is coming up with errors.

the project is a simple number guessing game.

says:

```
In function 'int main()':|
35|error: 'elif' was not declared in this scope|
35|error: expected ';' before '{' token|
37|error: expected ';' before '{' token|
40|error: 'else' without a previous 'if'|
```

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

main(){
    int upper = 100;
    int lower = 1;
    int guess;
    int answer;
    int turnCounter = 0;


    string name;

    cout << "Hello, welcome to the number game!" << endl;
    cout << "What's your name? " << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Nice to meet you " << name << "!" << endl;
    cout << "Ok let's get started, think of a number between 1 and 100, and I'll try to guess it!"
         << "If my guess is too high type a 1, if it is too low type a 0 or 10 if I get it right!" << endl;

    bool keepgoing = true;
    while (keepgoing){
            turnCounter ++;
            guess = (upper + lower)/ 2;
            cout << "Is the answer " << guess << "?" << endl;
            cin >> answer;
            if (answer == 1){
                upper = guess;
            } elif (answer == 0){
                lower = guess;
            } elif (answer == 10){
                cout << "Great! I'm so Awesome!" << endl;
                keepgoing = False;
            } else {
                cout << "Something went wrong, answer again: ";
                cin >> answer;
            }//end if loop
    } //end of while loop
}//end main
```

Comment: in c++ there is no such keyword as `elif`. You need `else if`

Answer (score 8):

1. `main ()` should be `int main ()`
2. `False` should be `false`
3. `elif` should be `else if`

This makes the code compile at least.

At your level of C++ knowledge you can pretty much trust the compiler to be right. If it says your code is broken, it really is.

Comment: yeah lol, i believed it I was just unaware that it was else if instead of elif (I just came from learning python) Thank you for your corrections!... Sorry took so long to respond, my internet got knocked out :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you come from a Python background?

Firstly there is no such keyword as `elif`.

You should use `else if` like

```
if (answer == 1){
    upper = guess;
} else if (answer == 0){
    lower = guess;
}
```

Also you should declare `False` as `false`.

Finally you have not declared an `int` return type for main. it should be declared as.

```
int main()
{
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: There is no implicit int in C++.

Comment: Strange Debian G++ 4.7.2-5 compiles fine without the return type. Maybe with a higher warning level it would complain.

Comment: g++ apparently requires `-pedantic`.

Comment: Actually, `-Wall` is sufficient.

Comment: But the `return 0;` is redundant in C++. If the program flows of the end of `main`, a value indicating successful termination is returned.

Comment: Omg it always seems to be the silly little mistakes >..<  Thank you for the corrections, and I apologize for my late response, as my internet got knocked out, and wasn't restored until today :(

Answer (score 0):

try else if instead of elif

```
 if (answer == 1){
        upper = guess;
    } else if (answer == 0){
        lower = guess;
```